# I can't open a torrent

Tags: file-management, torrents

I have μTorrent app, and I have a torrent file. I tried to open the file in standard file manager, but the manager shows "All apps associated with this action have been turned off, blocked, or are not installed". And there is no function in μTorrent to choose the file from memory.

Comment: Maybe its a broken uTorrent file. Check the hashes for integrity

Comment: Same issue. Solved by installing a different file manager. Just click on the downloaded torrent and away you go.

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Add torrent URL" and type the .torrent path like "file:///sdcard/Download/mytorrent.torrent"

Comment: This trick work's for me but on format.
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/abc.torrent